# Read CSV file in Kotlin

Tags: android, csv, kotlin

I want to read text from CSV file, when the code is in the class `MainActivity` it works ok, but when the code is in a function apart from this class it doesn't work. Shows "Unresolved reference open". How to make it work?

My code:

```
val bufferRead = BufferedReader(assets.open("test.csv").reader())
```

Comment: I needed this for jetpack compose, i think i found solution. When define function apart from MainActivity, then should looks like:
val context = LocalContext.current
val inputStream: InputStream = context.assets.open("test.csv")
val bufferRead = BufferedReader(inputStream.reader())